# How to check which host is primary in multiple URI using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm having three hosts(ex-XX.XX.XX.XX:P1,YY.YY.YY.YY:P2, ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ:P3)and i'm connecting these hosts with **pymongo.MongoClient()**. So can anyone guide me, how to find which host is primary using pymongo-3.7.1 with python-3.6?

Comment: Just suggestion: Always tag questions with tags without version also, so you will get faster answers like if you had tagged just pymongo, the reply would have come faster.

Comment: @daemon24 Thank you for telling this..

Answer (score 0):

MongoClient.primary will give you the current primary node's host,port

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
print(client.primary)
```

Reference : [MongoClient.primary](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.primary)

Comment: I checked with that only but when i'm giving multiple uri in MongoClient() e.g pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://[username:password]@[host1:port1],[host2:port2],[host3:post2]/database_name") then I'm not able to connect with it.

Comment: You are having the problem connecting to MongoDB or to find the primary host of MongoDB?

Comment: Initially i wanted to check the primary host but later that i found out that i'm not able to connect mongodb with multiple host uri that's why not able to get the primary host also.

Comment: ok, ask a different question with the connection issue with details.